# Retrieving the underlying error when File.listFiles return null

Tags: java, file-io

According to the [File.listFiles javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) the method

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

I know that I am using a directory, but have received a `null` result, so an I/O error must've appeared. I'm very much interested in what the error was.

How can I retrieve the error message/code when such a `null` result is returned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `java.nio.file.DirectoryStream` (in Java 7+) and you will get proper exceptions.

Answer (score 12):

You can't. Unfortunately the API doesn't provide you with a way to find out about the underlying I/O error.

#### See also

- [Bug 4505804: `File.listFiles()` requires `null` check on return value - should have better error handling](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4505804)

> The various `listFiles` methods of `File` all have the following annoying feature:
> they may possibly return `null` if an I/O error occurs.
>
> This behavior is very inconvenient, because it means that not only
> must I have code that handles `IOException`s (which is fine), but I also have to
> do additional `null` checks on the result.
>
> Better behavior would be that if an I/O error occurs, then an `IOException` always
> gets thrown.  You should not use a distinguished return value to sometimes
> indicate errors, and then also other times `throw Exception`s!
>
> **Evaluation**: We plan to address this longstanding problem in the forthcoming
> new filesystem API.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see [from an implementation of File](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/File.java.html), it will return `null` if

- the file is not a directory **or**
- the file does not exist **or**
- the directory is read-protected.

No evidence of a 'hidden' IOException although an I/O Error might occur in the native code.

Comment: The javadoc says nothing about an I/O Exception, but that an I/O error occurs. That suggests that there is no native error -> Exception translation.

Answer (score 0):

set perm to folder 311 (or something without read) and listFiles() will return null