# Exception errors in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have an error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException". Consider my code below.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String dir_name = "C:\\temp\\"; //Or another directory
    File dir = new File(dir_name);

    File[] dir_list = dir.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<dir_list.length;++i) {
        System.out.println(dir_list[i].getName())
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? I need some guidance.

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: The line with the for loop.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after the print statement.

Comment: I would imagine that your `File` isn't a directory.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  String dir_name = "C:\\temp\\"; //Or another directory
  File dir = new File(dir_name);

  if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()){
    File[] dir_list = dir.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<dir_list.length;++i) {
      System.out.println(dir_list[i].getName());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: your solution helps get rid of the error, but the outcome of the code is meant to print out a list of all the file is the named directory, but this is not the case.

Comment: @Hustl3r28 if the `File` you have given it doesn't exist or isn't a directory how do you expect it to list files?

Comment: @Hustl3r28 What is your case?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that your problem is that `dir.listFiles()` returns `null` because `dir` is not seen as a valid directory by Java. As said in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29):

> *Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.*

So maybe your Java application does not have the rights to access `C:\Temp\`, or the string `C:\\Temp\\` is misinterpreted as a parameter to the file object, or simply it does not exists. I can't tell, but you should definitely check whether `dir == null` and throw an exception when that happen. And also find out why you can't access `C:\temp\`.

As a check, I can only follow @ZhenxiaHoa code example, and add to that the throwing of an exception to make that error stand out:

```
if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()){
    File[] dir_list = dir.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<dir_list.length;++i) {
        System.out.println(dir_list[i].getName());
    }
} else {
    throw IOException("Can't access directory");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228147/retrieving-the-underlying-error-when-file-listfiles-return-null).

The null means there was an error.